# rsync question: How do you sync files in a folder pointed to by a symlink?

Tags: rsync, symlink

I have two linux machines with identical directory structures and I'm trying to sync 2 directories in `/home/inkjet`. One of the directories is an actual directory and one is a symlink to a directory. The `/home/inkjet` folder looks like this on both machines:

```
ls -l /home/inkjet
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          1024 Aug 16 17:44 other
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root          1024 Aug 17 06:21 bmps
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            22 Aug 17 05:39 fnts -> /usr/local/inkjet/fnts
```

The machine that is running `rsync --daemon` has the following `/etc/rsyncd.conf`:

```
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
lock file = /var/run/rsync.lock
log file = /var/log/rsync.log
port = 12000

[files]
path = /home/inkjet
comment = RSYNC FILES
read only = no
hosts allow = 192.168.4.1
```

If I run rsync with `-r --delete` options on the client:

```
rsync -r --delete /home/inkjet/bmps /home/inkjet/fnts rsync://192.168.4.94:12000/files
skipping non-regular file "fnts"
```

The `/home/inkjet/bmps` folder works fine, but the `/home/inkjet/fnts` folder fails because it is a symlink. If I add `--copy-dirlinks` and `--keep-dirlinks` options:

```
rsync -rkK --delete /home/inkjet/prds /home/inkjet/fnts rsync://192.168.4.94:12000/files
rsync: delete_file: unlink(fnts) failed: Permission denied (13)
could not make way for new directory: fnts
```

What options are needed to get the files in `/home/inkjet/fnts (->/usr/local/inkjet/fnts)` synced (without creating another module `/usr/local/inkjet` and running rsync on it too)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you `rsync` directories you should always add a trailing `/`. This is partly so that subsequent syncs don't try to create a new directory inside an older one, and partly to avoid this problem.

Unfortunately this makes the meaning different when syncing multiple directories, so you need to use multiple commands:

```
rsync -rkK --delete /home/inkjet/fnts/ rsync://192.168.4.94:12000/files/fnts/
rsync -rkK --delete /home/inkjet/prds/ rsync://192.168.4.94:12000/files/prds/
```